# How do I use or config Mybatis default LongTypeHandler

Tags: mybatis, typehandler

### sql xml define

When I use Mybatis **LongTypeHandler** in **resultMap**, I got error bellow, I don't know why. Does anyone could help on this?
Thanks in advance.

```xml
<resultMap id="detail_siteTypeConfig" type="java.util.HashMap">
        <result typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.LongTypeHandler" javaType="java.lang.Long" property="siteID" column="siteid"/>
        <result typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.LongTypeHandler" javaType="java.lang.Long" property="siteType" column="sitetype"/>
        <result typeHandler="com.webex.webapp.common.util.mybatis.StringEmptyTypeHandler" javaType="java.lang.String" property="itemName" column="itemname"/>
        <result typeHandler="com.webex.webapp.common.util.mybatis.StringEmptyTypeHandler" javaType="java.lang.String" property="itemValue" column="itemvalue"/>
    </resultMap>    

    <select id="xxxxxx" resultMap="detail_siteTypeConfig">
        select siteid, sitetype, itemname, itemvalue from tablexxxx where siteid=#{siteId} and sitetype=#{siteType}
    </select>
```

### Error log

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'conf/dao/basic/SessionType_Audit.xml'. Cause: org.
apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Unable to find a usable constructor for class org.apache.ibatis.type.LongTypeHandler
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:123)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:95)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.mapperElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:377)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:120)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Unable to find a usable constructor for class org.apache.ibatis.type.LongTypeHandler
at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandlerRegistry.getInstance(TypeHandlerRegistry.java:457)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveTypeHandler(BaseBuilder.java:143)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.buildResultMapping(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:427)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildResultMappingFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:393)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:280)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:254)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElements(XMLMapperBuilder.java:246)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:119)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ibatis.type.LongTypeHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler
at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandlerRegistry.getInstance(TypeHandlerRegistry.java:455)
... 32 more
```

Comment: Does anyone could help to check this ?
I got blocked

Comment: When I use a customized typeHandler, it works. :)

Comment: There may be multiple JARs of MyBatis in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Will verify @ave

Comment: Actually, I didn't find the root cause, but seems if use the one of the Mybatis default typeHandlers, we shouldn't declare a typeHandler explicitly in <result />

Comment: you dont'n need explicitely indicate the type handler if you intend to use the default one. If you remove the typeHandler attribute for java.util.Long the mapper will work fine.